# How can I find who made a change on the scope in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object on the scope, and someone is changing a property on it.

I can see it if I `$watch` the property, but for the life of me, I don't know who is changing it..

I searched the entire code for couple of days, and nothing comes up..

Is there a way in angular to find this out? Some data on the event that triggered the $watch or something like that?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj

Comment: First, do a global search in the project of the Variable that was being changed, so you know the possible places of it being used. If they are all in your js code, you can simply add different console logs before the lines it was called. You should be able to see which one was called when you $watch the changes. Otherwise, it could be changed in your html

Comment: this is not easy. javascript may have things like `myVar[myField] = myValue`  or `_.merge(obj1, obj2);` which will make things obscure.. anyways, I did it and still did not find where it is modified..